# Pycharm still displaying floats in dataframe after conversion to Int

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pycharm

I have a Dataframe that looks as follows:

[image]

But I need the Total distance in Route and Total distance to be Integer numbers, not floats. So I use:

```
output_df["Total Distance In Route (km)"] = output_df["Total Distance In Route (km)"].astype(int)
output_df["Total Distance (km)"] = output_df["Total Distance (km)"].astype(int)
```

But this doesn't change anything, all the numbers are still displayed in the same way.

Why is this?

Comment: If test `print (output_df.dtypes)` it return integers ?

Comment: Yes, it returns int32

Comment: It is correct, it is integer. It looks like some display issue

Comment: Hmm, Ok. Any suggestions on how to fix? My output will be automatically checked so If not ints it will be declined

Comment: hmmm, what IDE is used here? If write dataframe to file, it working correct?

Comment: I'm using PyCharm. Hmm, I tried to export the file as well and it seems to be fine. I didn't think it to be a PyCharm issue, since mostly Pycharm is very accurate in displaying DataFrames (e.g. when connecting debugger, df.drop() automatically removes row from dataframe displayed. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: hmmm, not idea, I dont use pycharm. I suggest change title of question for see pycharm problem

Comment: Updated title & tags, thx for response.